# Need to pass data to hidden text field in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I got the below solution here,

```
jse.executeScript("document.getElementsByName('body')[0].setAttribute('type', 'text');");
```

and then passing data using `SendKeys`.

But it is creating duplicate text field with text attribute and hidden text field still exist..

Comment: Please clarify the question along with the `html`. It's unclear what you are trying to accomplish. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to set the value of an `attribute`? The code you are using will add an additional `attribute`

Comment: builtYear is hidden type (<input id="builtYear" type="hidden") and i am trying to send some year to this field. I am just beginner in Selenium but got stuck up here. What should i do, to update an existing attribute?

Comment: Can you provide me the `html` of the year field? hidden should not be matter

Comment: See the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two input tags. I am assuming you want to execute the script against the second one not the first. 
Also, I am using `querySelector` and that allows you to pass `cssSelector` to identify the element you want.

*Note: Make sure the format of `dateToPass` is correct*

```
String dateToPass = "01/01/2015";
String scriptText = "document.querySelector('.propertyYear.require').setAttribute('value','" + dateToPass + "')";
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(scriptText);
```

Comment: You are awesome boss.. my 2 days headache is over.

Comment: Another question.. now i got another field to pass data, but i dont see any field to pass. <p>
<label>*First Name</label>
<br>
<input id="fName" type="hidden" name="fName">
<input class="fName require" maxlength="26">
<label id="invalidFN" class="test" style="display: none;">
<font color="#B91010" style="font-weight: normal;font-size: small;" ;=""> Please enter only alphabets.</font>
</label>
</p>

Comment: @arumugamdinesh What do you mean? Typing the text into name filed?

Comment: Yes. On previous example, there was value=" " field in BuiltYear. So we used setAttribute. But In this fname, i dont see any field to send/set..

Comment: Try `document.querySelector('.fName.require').setAttribute('value','saifur')`

Comment: No luck this time.. i dont see value field in html.. So SetAttribute(), cant be used here.